# How to configure local web app (Sinatra) and Router for external access?

Tags: networking, ip

How can I access my sinatra web application outside my local network?

I start my app with

```
$ ruby app.rb -o192.168.0.105 -p4567
== Sinatra (v2.0.5) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.7.2 codename Bachmanity)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 192.168.0.105:4567, CTRL+C to stop
192.168.0.105 - - [06/Jul/2019:08:58:58 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 0.0040
```

My router has this port forwarding:

[image]

Then I try to use my external IP - 34.62.43.89:4567 (not real one)

but I get

```
This site can’t be reached 24.61.43.68 took too long to respond.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

My local IP:
[image]

What do i have wrong / am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running ruby/sinatra on ubuntu operating system. Enabling IP forwarding would not be sufficient. You should also look into setting up internet gateway on your ubuntu machine (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#Ubuntu_Internet_Gateway_Method_.28iptables.29) and then try connecting with your public ip.